# Asymptote's 3D model is not correctly displayed in Acrobat Reader's fullscreen multimedia mode

Tags: 3d, asymptote, acrobat

Before enabling Acrobat Reader's fullscreen multimedia mode:
[image]

After enabling Acrobat Reader's fullscreen multimedia mode:
[image]

**Two questions:**

1. how to make the camera view is not changing.
2. how to make letters turn to the observer in Acrobat Reader's fullscreen multimedia mode.

The complete .tex file for generating the picture:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}
\begin{document}
\begin{asy}
import solids;
currentprojection = perspective(0,100,25);
viewportmargin=(0.1cm,0.1cm);
unitsize(5cm);
triple pO=(0,0,0);

real a=0.5;
revolution s=sphere(pO,a);

draw(surface(s),rgb(0.3,0.7,1)+opacity(0.3));
label("$A$",X,W);

axes3("$x$","$y$","$z$",min=(0,0,0),max=(1,1,1),Arrow3);
\end{asy}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What are the steps to compile this to PDF?

Comment: @AlexG unfortunately, I use overleaf and this code sits in .tex file of my project. I just compile this and download PDF.